# ED Vitals and CHARTEVENTS prior to ICU admission

Tags: mimic-iii

Are emergency department vital signs available in MIMIC III's CHARTEVENTS table?

I understand that medications and laboratory data is available throughout the entire hospital stay (not just in the ICU).  In testing a few patients, I can see some vital signs are available for some patients prior to ICU admission in CHARTEVENTS, but I'm not sure how reliably this is reported.

Some patients appear to have no CHARTEVENTS listed prior to 'intime' in the ICUSTAY table even though they are listed as being admitted through the emergency department, whereas other patients do have items within CHARTEVENTS.

Example with vital signs:

> select label, value
>   FROM chartevents CE
>   LEFT JOIN icustays ICU on ICU.icustay_id = CE.icustay_id
>   LEFT join admissions A on A.hadm_id = ICU.hadm_id
>   LEFT JOIN d_items ON d_items.itemid = CE.itemid
>   where A.hadm_id=157346 AND CE.charttime < ICU.intime

Example with no vital signs:

> select label, value
>   FROM chartevents CE
>   LEFT JOIN icustays ICU on ICU.icustay_id = CE.icustay_id
>   LEFT join admissions A on A.hadm_id = ICU.hadm_id
>   LEFT JOIN d_items ON d_items.itemid = CE.itemid
>   where A.hadm_id=176032 AND CE.charttime < ICU.intime

I understand that there may be some minor variability (+/- a few hours) with ICU admission times, but if a patient stays in the ED for an extended period of time prior to being admitted to the ICU, will the patient have metrics, such as blood pressure, recorded into CHARTEVENTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vital signs in MIMIC-III are captured from the CareVue/MetaVision intensive care systems, so this data is not available during the period of emergency care. Emergency care data is currently being integrated into MIMIC and we hope to make it available to researchers in the future.